# All my nuggets are depressed, what can I do?

Tags: the-universim

I keep using my god powers to make them happy, but that not enough. They are all very depressed.

I started the multiple researches to unlock culture and recreation, but is there another way to make them happy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to remember the game is still in Alpha and not balanced. For now the only way to stop the depression wave is to build local businesses, so try and get to that research so when your first nuggets start to bite the dust you're prepared.